# Erro ao ler string em C

Tags: c, string, scanf

Boa tarde pessoal! No meu programa utilizo o for para fazer a leitura de algumas strings que preenchem um vetor de struct. A primeira leitura ocorre normalmente, porém na segunda leitura o programa pula a leitura de uma string, eu acho que o erro pode estar no scanf, agradeço muito se puderem me ajudar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Troque a vírgula, em 1452,32 por ponto: 1452.32.

Comment: deu certo! muito obrigada!!

Answer (score 0):

Olá! O que está acontecendo é que o formatador de entrada `%[^\n]` não salva o seu *enter* digitado, porém ele ainda é capturado pelo seu buffer do teclado. Esse buffer fica "poluído" e interfere na leitura da próxima string.
Uma sugestão para contornar isso é limpar o seu buffer após uma leitura.

```
printf("Digite o nome do funcionário: ");
scanf("%s", nome);
__fpurge(stdin);
```

Obs: Lembrando que `__purge(stdin)` é pra sistemas Unix e `fflush(stdin)` é para windows